# Tokenizing a string error

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, token

im trying to tokenize some strings so that the numbers are tokens themselves so i can eventually add them but my tokenization is not working and im not sure why. It compiles correctly but when i execute the file it says "segmentation fault", anyone know why or how to get the number as tokens?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int stringSum(char *s);
/*void minMaxValues(char *s, int *min, int *max);*/

int main(void)
{
    int value,i;
    char* text[] = { "1 + 2 + 3 + 4",
                     "7",
                     "30 + 20 + 10",
                     "9 + 900 + 90000 + 9000 + 90" };
    for(i=0;i<4;i++) /*send strings to function*/
        stringSum(text[i]);
}

int stringSum(char *s)
{
    char* del = " + ";
    char* token;
    token = strtok(s,del);
    while(token != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n",token);
        token = strtok(NULL, del);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`strtok` requires modifiable strings. You defined an array of non-modifiable string literals in `main` and therefore they won't work with `strtok`.

For a quick solution, use:

```
char* temp = malloc(strlen(s) + 1);
strcpy(temp, s);
token = strtok(temp,del);
```

This dynamically allocates a modifiable string with the same value as `s` that you can use in `strtok`.

Since this is a dynamically allocated variable, remember to release the memory at the end of the method:

```
free(temp);
```

---

Your revised `stringSum` method should now look like this:

```
int stringSum(char *s)
{
    char* del = " + ";
    char* token;

    char* temp = malloc(strlen(s) + 1);
    strcpy(temp, s);
    token = strtok(temp,del);

    while(token != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n",token);
        token = strtok(NULL, del);
    }

    free(temp);
    return 0; //or whatever it is that you want to return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `strtok` modifies the original string. Try passing `char s[]` instead of `char* s` and

why did we use `char s[]`?

See the difference between `char pointer` and `char array` from here ([What is the difference between char s[] and char *s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c))

Answer (score 0):

```
token = strtok(s,del);
```

In the specifications of `strtok` function, `s`  has to be writeable but in your example it's a string literal.

```
char* text[] = { "1 + 2 + 3 + 4",
                 "7",
                 "30 + 20 + 10",
                 "9 + 900 + 90000 + 9000 + 90" };
```

All strings in the `text` array are string literals and are therefore unmodifiable.

Comment: so i can just copy the incoming string literal into a modifiable array and continue with it working?

Comment: @user3686360 for example, yes

Answer (score 0):

it is illegal strtok to change the first argument is a string literal can not change.

Alternative :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int stringSum(const char *s);

int main(void){
    int value, i, size;
    char *text[] = { "1 + 2 + 3 + 4",
                     "7",
                     "30 + 20 + 10",
                     "9 + 900 + 90000 + 9000 + 90"
    };
    size = sizeof(text)/sizeof(*text);
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        stringSum(text[i]);

    return 0;
}

int stringSum(const char *s){
    int sum = 0;
    char *endp;
    do{
        int num = strtol(s, &endp, 10);
        if(*endp == ' ' || *endp == '+' || *endp == '\0'){
            sum += num;
            if(*endp)
                s = ++endp;
        } else { //s has invalid character
            fprintf(stderr, "Illegal characters are included.\n");
            break;
        }
    }while(*endp);
    printf("%d\n", sum);
    return sum;
}
```